# PyQt не отрисовывается прямоугольник

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.5

Python 3.5, код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        MainWindow.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        # X
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        btn = QPushButton('Close', self)  # кнопака выхода иначе хрен закроеш
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 0, 1)
        self.move(10, 10)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        print('123')
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.draw_graph(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def draw_graph(self, event, qp):
        qp.setBrush(Qt.gray)
        qp.setPen(Qt.gray)
        qp.drawRect(250, 15, 90, 60)


class MyFirstGuiProgram(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)

        # Connect "add" button with a custom function (addInputTextToListbox)
        self.addBtn.clicked.connect(self.addInputTextToListbox)

    def addInputTextToListbox(self):
        txt = self.myTextInput.text()
        self.listWidget.addItem(txt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Не отрисовывается прямоугольник и не выводится принт в консоль. Что делать?

Comment: У вас код в целом очень странно написан. Зачем вы наследуете Ui_MainWindow от QWidget. Если в итоге из наследования ничего не используете. Опять же не понятно для чего вы два раза запускаете setupUi. Посмотрите пример, как это правильно делать https://www.codementor.io/deepaksingh04/design-simple-dialog-using-pyqt5-designer-tool-ajskrd09n.

Comment: А print у вас не печатается, по одной простой причине, метод paintEvent не срабатывает, потому что у вас неправильно проинициализировано основное окно.

Comment: В итоге еще и сделали так, что у вас QMainWindow становится QWidget, который в итоге помещается на этот же QMainWindow в качестве центрального виджета. Так работать точно не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрите простой вариант просто окно и в нем отрисованный прямоугольник:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("paintEvent")
        qp = Qt.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.Qt.gray)
        qp.setPen(Qt.Qt.gray)
        qp.drawRect(250, 15, 90, 60)
        qp.end()
        return Qt.QWidget.paintEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

После того как у вас отрисовалось все что нужно, используйте этот виджет в вашей программе. Можно добавить его в `QMainWindow` или использовать самостоятельно.